# IIS Express 8 - Cannot write configuration file

Tags: iis-express, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use IIS Express 8 for a MVC site in VS2012. I am getting the following error whenever I attempt to create the site:

> Filename:
>   \?\C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationHost.config
>   Error: Cannot write configuration file

Is there some way to force IIS Express to use a different location for the config & logs folders? I understand I can point to a different location when I am running iisexpress.exe from the command line, but I have no control over this when using Visual Studio.

Alternatively, has anyone got any suggestions why the error is happening? (Side note: My laptop is in a corporate environment which has some stupid encryption on the "Documents" folder, however I haven't had any problems with other software that saves to this location. I also have given the "Everyone" group full access to the folder.)

**EDIT - After following the instructions at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1286/iis-80-express-readme/ I still can't seem to get this working. I've tried the following:**

- Added HKCU\Software\Microsoft\IISExpress\CustomUserHome registry key pointing to my alternate directory
- Added HKCU\Software\Microsoft\IISExpress\8.0\CustomUserHome registry key pointing to my alternate directory
- Added HKLM\Software\Microsoft\IISExpress\CustomUserHome registry key pointing to my alternate directory
- Added HKLM\Software\Microsoft\IISExpress\8.0\CustomUserHome registry key pointing to my alternate directory
- Setting the %IIS_USER_HOME% environment variable pointing to my alternate directory.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have the same problem. None of the solutions mentioned here have worked. At the moment this hinders our team adopting vs 2012.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

@Brad

I had your same problem just now. Removing the encryption on the IISExpress folder and the "Read Only" attribute solved it. In my company Documents is also encrypted, but I don't think removing that encryption from IISExpress would be a problem of any sort.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't have encryption set, but I did have to remove the "Read Only" attribute AND run VS2012 as Administrator.

Comment: Removed encryption and read only.. Works like a charm! Thanks!!

Comment: In case this is not the answer for you and If you find yourself in my situation, I deleted the .vs directory to clear the cache and didn't notice that Visual Studio had changed my default build configuration to an auto-generated one that was configured to use IISExpress. So if you had a project that was working fine and then stops loading, I'd suggest before you do anything else to check the build config (which I of course failed to do)

Comment: Oops, while my previous 'helpful' comment was accurate it was not the root cause of the cryptic error message. That would be the fact that the automatically recreated .vs folder inherited NTFS encryption. Back to normal without needing to edit the project file after decrypting that folder.

Answer (score 10):

I had a very similar error message caused by a completely different problem.

The Error:

> C:\VS\TFS_Projects\SomeSolution\SomeProject\SomeProject.csproj : error  : **Creation of the virtual directory http://localhost:55063/ failed** with the error: Filename: \\?\C:\VS\TFS_Projects\SomeSolution.vs\config\applicationhost.config
>   Error: **Cannot write configuration file due to insufficient permissions**

More Details: I couldn't even open the project, as opening it would fail.

I could get prior changesets, and they would actually open fine, but if I got latest the projects couldn't be opened.

**Solution:**  In my case, it turned out that when we changed TFS servers, someone had added the "**.vs**" folder to source control along with everything else.  Under which, one developer had his **applicationhost.config** set up to run sites on a D:\ drive, while I had no such D:\ drive (well, it was a DVD drive.)  I was able to get this working by finding a prior changeset with the un-altered applicationhost.config and replacing my local file.  (I could have attempted to actually delete the folder, but I didn't go that route.)

Afterwards, we removed the ".vs" folder from source control.

(I put this solution here because it's where google landed me, so other people having this error message might find the above solutions don't fix it for them, and thus they might be having this problem.)

Comment: This appears to be my issue, but removing the .vs folder only worked for a day - the next day all stations again have the issue, but no .vs folder. We can't open one of our ASP projects across the department. :-/

Comment: This solved my problem.  I was creating new development projects using GIt so I could work on two things at once.
I wonder if the ".vs" folder should even be in the base Git image.

Answer (score 5):

I'm also in a corporate environment with Encryption on the users folder, and removing encryption and removing the read only flags on everything in the IISExpress folder worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 and to fix this problem I had to disable the OneDrive setting "Save space and download files as you use them". After changing the setting my computer crashed but after rebooting I was then able to change SSL Enabled and everything worked.

Comment: You can keep that setting on, and right click a specific one drive folder to "always keep on this device".

Answer (score 3):

For anyone googling this; this might be the same problem as this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/878812/use-iis-express-is-broken-in-vs-2012-on-windows-8-1

You can check it by downloading [Prcocess Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/da-dk/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and run it with a filter for "Path" contains "\Documents\IISExpress\config" and then try to change the project to use IIS Express. If there is a CreateFile entry with the result 0xC0190052 as one of the last entries then this is the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with this, and verifying encryption and read-only attributes, and having them not work, my solution ended up being:

- Navigate to the folder containing the IISExpress folder (in my case, it was in my OneDrive, not Documents folder)
- Right click on `IISExpress` folder > Security tab > Advanced button
- Change Owner to yourself, even if it already is
- Check the "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects" box

  - This may not appear until you've completed the Change owner dialog
- Open the `IISExpress` folder
- Right click on `config` folder > Security tab > Advanced button
- Add a user > Add principal
- Change location to local machine (and not a domain)
- Enter the name `NETWORK SERVICE` and "Check Names"
- Press OK to get back to the Advance Security dialog
- Make sure to check "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object"

Worked in Windows 10 with IISExpress 10, for both VS 2013 and VS 2017.

Answer (score 1):

C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationHost.config

Uncheck the read-only attribute from the file. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the registry entry seemed to work, however, using environment variables in the registry entry did not.  In my environment only our documents directory is redirected, so I simply wanted to move the IIS Express config directory up one level to the %USERPROFILE% directory.  However, that did not work.  IIS Express read the environment variable literally and of course failed to run.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before, running VisualStudio as Administrator (Run as Administrtor) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem and tried to fix it with setting the registry key in HKCU\Software\Microsoft which didn't work.

The error I made, was using HKCU because, since I do not have permissions to edit the registry under by normal account (which I use to run visual studio), I was using an administrative account. Then of course, HKCU was for that account.

So I just used HKEY_USERS\"my normal user's SID" instead and, when starting iisexpress.exe manually, it created its files at the location indicated. What still didn't work was using iisexpress from visual studio. It still seemed that VS didn't use the registry setting at all.

Finally I resorted in setting a non UNC path for Shell Folders\Personal and User Shell Folders\Personal in HKU\"my normal user's SID"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ which did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error but in a different context.  Opening a project (.csproj file) provided by another developer returned this error and failed to do anything:

> Creating of the virtual directory http://localhost:58753/
>   failed with the error: 
>   Filename: \?\C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Clients\xxx\Gen
>   II\xxx\,vs\config\applicationhost.config 
>   Error: Cannot write configuration file

I removed both Encryption and the R/O attribute from the directory containing the project files and applied to all subfolders and files.  Visual Studio can now read the project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I moved the folder to another location, so I had to edit the applicationhost.config file and changed the virtualdirectory entry to the new location.  Removing encryption and setting read only off did not help.  I imagine if I had just copied it instead of moving it, it would have happily continued working.